# How to go about formatting code without hurting the DRY principle in java + PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, dry

Pardon the shadiness of the question, allow me to explain myself.

I created a PDFGenerator using PDFBox. The PDF is around 9 pages, the actual PDFGenerator.java is a monster with almost 4k lines of code, a large portion of the code being the constant pixel positioning of the text(s) inside the PDF.

The current version (v1) includes 2 main variables, a supply and an exhaust. So for every line of something there is a supply value and an exhaust value.

The entire thing works perfectly, and I am very satisfied with the entire generation process. However now v2 has come, and the customer wants a possibility to create either **supply or exhaust, or both**.

This is where my problem with the DRY principle comes in. Theoretically, the code for both is already there. And the only thing that changes when it's one or the other, is the positioning of the text, which now gets centered between the 2 columns.

Example: Both (currently being generated)

**Attributes ............. Supply ......... Exhaust**

Height ..........................5....................5

Width ...........................5....................5

Example: One or the other

**Attributes ........................ Supply .........**

Height ....................................5...............

Width .....................................5...............

Here is a block that generates one line:

```
    pdContentStream.beginText();
    pdContentStream.setFont(boldFont, BOLD_FONT_SIZE);
    pdContentStream.newLineAtOffset(TEXT_BEGIN, currentYCoord);
    pdContentStream.showText(messageSource.getMessage("pdf.value.TDVentilator", null, this.locale));
    pdContentStream.endText();

    pdContentStream.beginText();
    pdContentStream.setFont(boldFont, BOLD_FONT_SIZE);
    pdContentStream.newLineAtOffset(SUPPLY_BEGIN, currentYCoord);
    pdContentStream.showText(messageSource.getMessage("pdf.supply", null, this.locale));
    pdContentStream.endText();

    pdContentStream.beginText();
    pdContentStream.setFont(boldFont, BOLD_FONT_SIZE);
    pdContentStream.newLineAtOffset(EXHAUST_BEGIN, currentYCoord);
    pdContentStream.showText(messageSource.getMessage("pdf.exhaust", null, this.locale));
    pdContentStream.endText();
```

Remember, these kind of blocks repeat themselves throughout the entire generation process. Now is where my DRY problem comes in.

The first thing that comes to my mind, is to export the current code into a function used only for generating both, and create (copy/paste) a second function that is used for one or the other. But a large portion of the code would repeat itself doing this (with one less block since we have only one output variable and not two).

The other way that I can think of is to create a if() before every code block, if this case then take that block, if that case take that block. Once again, DRYness is not there (since the same if would have to come before every code block).

My question is: What would generally be the best way to go about this? I don't mind if the monster grows again from 4k to 8k lines of code, but if there is a simpler (better) way to do it I am all ears.

Cheers :)

Comment: You don't have to set the font each time, only if it changes. And you don't have to do beginText / endText each time, however note that your offset values passed to `newLineAtOffset` are relative to the previous offset. (the first being 0,0). If you output less then the result PDF file will be smaller which is a good thing if you store them or send from on a http line.

Comment: For your unit tests (you hopefully do unit tests), I recommend that you do a rendering of your PDFs and compare the image results. This way you can be sure that the PDFs remain the same after your refactoring. See TestPDFToImage.java for how inspiration.

Comment: Aye mate, of course i do unit tests *cough cough* :) Interesting thing to note there (maybe it will help someone somewhen). I ran a classic file compare test to see if a hardcopy of the PDF was same as one being generated and it kept throwing errors even though they were absolutely identical. Turns out the PDF sets a new ID every time, this ID can be statically set via "pdfDocument.setDocumentId(1);" After doing that the tests passed no problem. Of course the static id is only set for testing, for deployment it is the generated one as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
pdContentStream.beginText();
pdContentStream.setFont(boldFont, BOLD_FONT_SIZE);
pdContentStream.newLineAtOffset(EXHAUST_BEGIN, currentYCoord);
pdContentStream.showText(messageSource.getMessage("pdf.exhaust", null, this.locale));
pdContentStream.endText();
```

The **only** part that I see to be different is the first parameter given to `messageSource.getMessage()`.

So your refactoring would probably start with introducing:

```
public void prepareContent(Whatever pdContentStream, String message) {
    pdContentStream.beginText();
    pdContentStream.setFont(boldFont, BOLD_FONT_SIZE);
    pdContentStream.newLineAtOffset(EXHAUST_BEGIN, currentYCoord);
    pdContentStream.showText(messageSource.getMessage(message, null, this.locale));
    pdContentStream.endText();
}
```

And then your main code boils down to:

```
prepareContent(pdContenStream, "pdf.value.TDVentilator");
prepareContent(pdContenStream, "...
```

and so on. Then: you would probably put that stuff in its own class, in which you make `pdContentStream` a field; to git rid of needing that parameter for each call.

After that should be looking into "organizing" those strings better. There is no point in writing down:

```
foo("bla");
foo("blub");
```

Instead you push those values like "pdf.value.TDVentilator" into a **List**; to then imply iterate lists/sets/whatever, to fetch the required info from there.

Long story short: you don't grow monsters. You don't even allow them to exist. The code you are showing is already a **harsh** violation of DRY that should absolutely **not** be tolerated!

Comment: Thanks mate, the idea to use a list (or more exactly spoken, a map) was perfect. I packed the texts into the map and through iterating easily get entire pages generated from 20 lines of code. I also managed to reduce the monster from over 4k to around 1k lines :) 

I have no idea what went though my head when i wrote the original code, but i definitely know now not to make a mistake like that again.